# to_number(text) does not exit can you help here?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am using select to_number(to_char(now(),'YYYYMMDD24MISS')) but I am getting error as function to_number(text) does not exit ..can you help me

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and receives not more security patches. You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) `to_number()` needs two arguments. The second being the format to be applied:

```
to_number(to_char(now(),'YYYYMMDD24MISS'), '99999999999999')
```

Alternatively, just cast it to a bigint:

```
to_char(now(),'YYYYMMDD24MISS')::bigint
```